# Check some settings in debian/ubuntu and the output should be similar to testssh

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting, debian

I have a script that checks some settings in debian/ubuntu, for example:

```
grub=$(stat /boot/grub/grub.cfg)
if [[ $grub = *"(0444/-r--r--r--)"* ]]  
then 
   echo "Access: (0444/-r--r--r--) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root) is set on stat /boot/grub/grub.cfg."
else 
  echo "ERROR: Access: (0444/-r--r--r--) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root) is not set on stat /boot/grub/grub.cfg."
  stat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
fi

user=$( stat /boot/grub/user.cfg )
if [[ $user = *"(0444/-r--r--r--)"* ]] 
then 
   echo "Access: (0444/-r--r--r--) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root) is set on stat /boot/grub/user.cfg"
else 
  echo "ERROR: Access: (0444/-r--r--r--) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root) is not set on stat /boot/grub/user.cfg"
  stat /boot/grub/user.cfg
fi
```

And I want this script to show me only ERROR/Access without the output of the command "stat /boot/grub/grub.cfg" such as "the file or folder does not exist" or something similar.
As if the command run background, and it would only show me if it's ok or not. Same as testssh.sh .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zN23.png)
Without "stat: cannot statx '/boot/grub/user.cfg': No such file or directory" only "ERROR: Access: (0444/-r--r--r--) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root) is not set on stat /boot/grub/user.cfg
".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the existence of the file before running `stat` on it.

```bash
if [ -e /boot/grub/grub.cfg ]; then
 # run stat on /boot/grub/grub.cfg
fi
```

You also might want to check the manpage for `stat` to only output the data you want, rather than doing wildcard matching.
and use functions to keep your code DRY.

Here's a version of your script that does not depend on bashisms:

```bash
checkperms() {
  if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    local perms
    perms=$(stat -c %a "$1")
    if [ "${perms}" = 444 ]; then
      echo "Access OK for $1"
    else 
      echo "ERROR: wrong Access for $1"  1>&2
      stat "$1"
    fi
  fi
}
checkperms /boot/grub/grub.cfg
checkperms /boot/grub/user.cfg
```